# TikZ figure not aligned with other subfigure when title is long

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, captions, subfloats

I am trying to get two tikzpictures next to each other via two subfigure environments.
As you can see in the first picture they are not horizontally aligned. You can see how it should look in the second picture.

I have noticed a few things:

- When the title is to long, the pictures are unaligned. A shorter title is fine.
- When i give each subfigure a width of `0.4\textwidth` the pictures are unaligned. A smaller width is fine.
- When i comment out the captions the pictures are aligned.

Thanks in advance

First Picture:

[image: Unaligned with longer title]

Second Picture:

[image: Aligned with short title]

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \input{figures/chapter_1/Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion.tex}
            \caption{Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion der Haushaltsgröße.}
            \label{fig:Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \input{figures/chapter_1/Verteilungsfunktion.tex}
            \caption{Verteilungsfunktion der Haushaltsgröße.}
            \label{fig:Verteilungsfunktion}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion.tex

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.8.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{%
    width=\textwidth
}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.56078431372549,0.835294117647059}
\begin{axis}[
axis line style={white!94.1176470588235!black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
title={short title},
x grid style={white!79.6078431372549!black},
xlabel={\(\displaystyle  x \in \Omega\)},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-0.75, xmax=4.75,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!79.6078431372549!black},
ylabel={Wahrscheinlichkeit},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=0, ymax=0.42,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:-0.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.5,0.1);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:0.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:1.5,0.2);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:1.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:2.5,0.4);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:2.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:3.5,0.2);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:3.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:4.5,0.1);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Verteilungsfunktion.tex

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.8.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{%
    width=\textwidth
}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.56078431372549,0.835294117647059}
\begin{axis}[
axis line style={white!94.1176470588235!black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
title={Verteilungsfunktion \(\displaystyle F(x)\)},
x grid style={white!79.6078431372549!black},
xlabel={\(\displaystyle  x \in \Omega\)},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-0.75, xmax=4.75,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!79.6078431372549!black},
ylabel={Wahrscheinlichkeit},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=0, ymax=1.05,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:-0.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.5,0.1);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:0.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:1.5,0.3);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:1.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:2.5,0.7);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:2.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:3.5,0.9);
\draw[draw=black,fill=color0,very thick] (axis cs:3.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:4.5,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please post a `Minimal Complete Example` that we can cut and paste to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple MWE and the exact code you provided, I don't get any misalignment between the figures.

So the problem must be elsewhere in your code.

To debug it, run my example on your system, to verify it works, and then start adding packages and commands one by one.

[image: x2]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion}
        \caption{Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion der Haushaltsgröße.}
        \label{fig:Wahrscheinlichkeitsfunktion}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{Verteilungsfunktion}
        \caption{Verteilungsfunktion der Haushaltsgröße.}
        \label{fig:Verteilungsfunktion}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 
    
\end{document}
```